# Check value of AutoResetEvent without affecting event

Tags: .net, multithreading, autoresetevent

I'm creating some "instrumentation" inside a multi-threaded server in .NET (C#).

It's fairly easy to check the value of a .NET `ManualResetEvent` without concern for changing the value:

```
aManualResetEvent.WaitOne( 0 );
```

returns a boolean without waiting on the event.

However, I seem to be at a loss for getting the same information from an `AutoResetEvent`; if you call `anAutoResetEvent.WaitOne( 0 )` on a `set` event, it will reset the event while returning (by definition).

The best option I can determine at this point is to change the `AutoResetEvent` to a `ManualResetEvent` and manually reset when actually testing the event:

```
ManualResetEvent theEventFormerlyKnownAsAutoResetEvent;
...


// Using the event:
if ( theEventFormerlyKnownAsAutoResetEvent.WaitOne( timeout )
{
    theEventFormerlyKnownAsAutoResetEvent.Reset();
    ...
}
...

// Instrumentation to get event state (shouldn't change anything):
bool eventIsSet = theEventFormerlyKnownAsAutoResetEvent.WaitOne( 0 );
// Update instrumentation
```

Is there a better way of checking the state of an `AutoResetEvent`?  I would prefer the intrinsic atomicity of the `AutoResetEvent` if possible.

Comment: That would be useless, since someone else might clear the event just after you check it.

Comment: With that reasoning, eyesight is useless, since you are seeing something that might no longer be there.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point here is atomicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of `AutoResetEvent` is to release one and only one waiting thread when the event transitions to a signalled state.  If you used the signalled state to do something specific in one thread, you risk getting into a race condition or a deadlock between threads if another thread can still wait on the event's signal--one of the reasons for using `AutoResetEvent`.

If you provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, maybe someone can provide an alternative that would help.

Comment: Just trying to build in instrumentation on the state of the events; I want to know the state of the AutoResetEvent without triggering it -- that is, no action can be taken as a result of peeking at the data (except changing an unrelated display setting).

Comment: That's not something that is supported--there's nothing in the underling Win32 API to get that information.  You'd have to set a flag somewhere in the code after the call the `Wait`...

Comment: I suspected as much; besides, in the wrong hands (including mine) it would be dangerous...